# Can't display navbar list items on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for navbar.

```
<div style="margin-bottom:60px; background-color:lightblue" class="navbar-header navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">

    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;" rel="home" href="#" title="">
        <img style="max-width:60px; margin-top: -7px;" class="img-circle"
             src="~/Content/Images/Logo.jpeg"> <em>JOM</em>
    </a>
    <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Index", "Book")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Index", "Checkout")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkin", "Index", "Checkin")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The list items (i.e, Students, Books, Checkout, Checkin) appear on desktop but not on mobile. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Desktop Version]

[image: Mobile Version]

As you can see, the mobile version does not have the 4 links.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Hi Deepu, Unfortunately I can't. It's a private url.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the nav bar wrapped in a `.navbar`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JOM</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Index", "Book")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Index", "Checkout")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkin", "Index", "Checkin")</li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Comment: That certainly was the issue. But I remember removing it solely because if I add the nav tag, I get an empty white space above my navigation bar and it's really annoying. Is there a way to ensure that the nav bar sits right at the top and does not have any white spacw above it?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that spacing issue with the code snippet you provided. Are you able to provide a sample that demonstrates this issue?